# AP Calculus BC - Polar curve question

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

> A particle moving along the polar curve given by $r = 2 + 2\sin(\theta)$ has position $(x(t),y(t))$ at time $t$, with $\theta = 0$ when $t = 0$. This particle moves along the curve so that $\frac{dr}{dt} = \frac{dr}{d\theta}$. What is the value of $\frac{dr}{dt}$ at $\theta = \frac{\pi}{6}$?  (Calculator allowed)

I literally have no idea what to do for this problem. What is the significance of $\frac{dr}{dt} = \frac{dr}{d\theta}$? I'm guessing that means that $2\cos(\theta) = \frac{dr}{d\theta}$, but what the hell is $\frac{dr}{d\theta}$? A step-by-step explanation would be really great.

Answer choices:

a) $\sqrt{3}$

b) $\frac{1}{2}$

c) $\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$

d) $1$

Comment: From $r=2+2\sin \theta$, you compute $dr/d\theta$, and get $2\cos\theta$, correct.  So $dr/dt = 2\cos\theta$.  At $\theta=\pi/6$, we get...

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: @GEdgar Ah - so I plug in $π/6$ in $dr/dt$, and $2cos(π/6)$ = root(3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$ \frac {dr}{dθ} = 2cos(θ) $

But :  $ \frac {dr}{dθ} = \frac {dr}{dt} = 2cos(θ) $

So $ \frac {dr}{dt} $ for $θ = \frac {\pi}{6} $ is : $ 2cos(\frac {\pi}{6}) = \sqrt{3} $

Comment: So $\frac {dr}{dt}=2cos(\theta)=2sin(\theta)$?

Comment: Lulu, yep I apologise. Just woke up and answered this and my mind was shaking, edited right now. Can't get really the point of the exercise tho because it's meaningless unless it wants you to find the equations and just practice in basic calculus. But ye, epic mistake :P

Comment: But even post edit....$\theta$ is a non-trivial function of time so you can't integrate it the way you did.  The problem is simpler than you are making it...as you remark, $\frac {dr}{dt} =2cos(\theta)$ so you just have to evaluate.

Comment: Meh .. you're right. Forgot for a moment the physics part that $θ$ is connected to time $t$.